Adhoc Converts with Multiset & JPA
I have the following database tables:
order            line
- id             - parentid
- sub            - linenum
- approved       - total
                 - product

And the following POJOs with @Column annotations:
public class Order {

  @Column(name = "id")
  private Integer orderId;

  @Column(name = "sub")
  private Double subtotal;

  @Column(name = "approved")
  private Boolean approved;

  private List<OrderLine> orderLines;
}

public class OrderLine {

  @Column(name = "parentid")
  private Integer parentId;

  @Column(name = "linenum")
  private Integer lineNumber;

  @Column(name = "total")
  private Double lineTotal;

  @Column(name = "product")
  private String product;

}

I write a query like the
create.select(
    ORDER.ID, ORDER.SUB, ORDER.APPROVED,
    multiset(
      select(LINE.PARENTID, LINE.LINENUM, LINE.TOTAL, LINE.PRODUCT)
      .from(LINE)
      .where(LINE.PARENTID.eq(ORDER.ID))
    .as("order_lines")
  ).from(ORDER)
  .where(ORDER.ID.eq(100));

I'd like to fetch the results of this into the Order POJO.
Doing the following
fetchInto(Order.class) works for Order fields, but I am unsure of how to handle the multiset and OrderLines. Is it possible to jOOQ to use the JPA @Column annotations?

The DefaultRecordMapper, which implements the fetchInto(Order.class) style methods, has only limited support for nested collections. This is mainly because of generic type erasure on your Order class, where List<OrderLine> doesn't tell jOOQ much at runtime, because it's just List (the raw type).
You could nest your DefaultRecordMapper usage and map your multiset() directly with an ad-hoc converter:
    multiset(
      select(LINE.PARENTID, LINE.LINENUM, LINE.TOTAL, LINE.PRODUCT)
      .from(LINE)
      .where(LINE.PARENTID.eq(ORDER.ID))
    .convertFrom(r -> r.into(OrderLine.class))
    .as("order_lines")

At this point, I'd like to point out that from the jOOQ perspective, it's better to use type safe mapping using constructor references because:

You get direct compiler feedback on all of your mappings
It's much easier to debug when something goes wrong in a very complex query
It's faster than the reflection usage


Unfortunately, that did not work. I stepped through the mapping code and I can see that the OrderLine's are being constructed and populated, but they do not end up in the List in the Order class. Is there something I need to annotate the Order class with so that it is populated? Could it be an issue with naming?

Have you tried adding a @Column annotation to your list? It's not correct in JPA, but jOOQ requires it on all columns if you want to map them. There's a feature request here to make them optionl...

Yes I figured that out after doing some testing! Also, I'd love to use the type-safe methods you mentioned above, but this object is much higher than the 22nd degree.

@Conner: You could nest common things both in jOOQ and in your target DTO?

Not sure what you mean there.

@Conner https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/nested-records/
